# HttpClient: cancellation async HTTP request with ObjectContent

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

In code below Wait() method will never throws exception caused by task cancellation, and never returns control to calling thread.

```
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://stackoverflow.com")
    {
        Content = new ObjectContent<Foo>(new Foo(), new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
    };
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    Task task = client.SendAsync(request, cts.Token);
    cts.Cancel();
    task.Wait();
```

But when request.Content is StringContent with serialized Foo object, exception is thrown. My expectation is that exception will be thrown with all HttpContent types.

1. Why exception is not thrown?
2. Workaround with creating StringContent is not good. Maybe
           another workaround exists?

Comment: What exception are you getting exactly? Please post the details.  Why would you be calling Cancel immediately after making your call?

Comment: My expectation: Wait() method must throw AggregateException with TaskCancelledException in InnerException property. Cancel() may be called at any time moment, including right after creating task.

Comment: Could you replace `task.Wait();` with `var result = task.Result;` and inspect the result? Curious to know if the call is actually completing successfully. (I assume this is for illustrative purposes so I'll spare you the lecture about doing this asynchronously with `await` :)

Comment: Wait() never returns control to calling thread. Added this to my question, thank you for comment. And yes, it is for illustrative purposes :)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote classic async deadlock the task.Wait waits for operation, which will never complete, as your thread is blocked in the "Wait". 
You need to AWAIT the task, then it will work as expected. The cancel exception will be thrown on await line.

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://stackoverflow.com")
{
    Content = new ObjectContent<Foo>(new Foo(), new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
};
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
Task task = client.SendAsync(request, cts.Token);
cts.Cancel();
await task;
```